# lambda expression is not changing the values of pandas' dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the following function to change the value of column 'A' to np.NaN if the current value is '...'. However, for some reason, nothing is changing.

```
def findEmpty(row):
    row['A'] = np.NaN


energy[energy['A'] == '...'].apply(lambda x:findEmpty(x))
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Why don't you use fillna?

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: I am learning python, and I would like to know how to use lambda in this scenario. @anshanno

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a much more efficient solution

```
energy.ix[(energy['A'] == '...'), 'A'] = np.NaN
```

be aware that lambda functions are in pure Python. In other words, you basically throw away all the nice C speed-ups in Pandas when you do so. If you use large datasets, always try to avoid loops and lambda functions (when possible)

Answer (score 2):

Pandas `apply` returns a `DataFrame` with applied values.
Try this:

```
energy = energy[energy['A'] == '...'].apply(lambda x:findEmpty(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a 'replace' method which would improve the readability

```
energy.replace('...', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```